# How to subscribe to a scroll event and other of D3.js events in VizFrame?

Tags: events, d3.js, sapui5

I need to take a scroll event from VizFrame. How I can do that?

`._vizInstance.on('scroll', console.log)` doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try listening for "mousewheel" instead of "scroll"? That is what is needed for trackpad scrolling:

```
d3.select('.whatever').on('mousewheel', callback);
```